# Filter a 2D list with String

Tags: python, string, list

I want to define a function that will take a 2D list and a string.The function will remove every secound list that has any element of the string.

```py
def base_remover(s, l):
    for i in l:
        for j in i:
            for k in s:
                if k == j:
                    l.remove(i)
    return l
l=[['2', '4'], ['2', '1'], ['5', '2'], ['3', '7'], ['4', '7'], ['6', '7']]
s="1536"
print(base_remover(s, l))
```

I expect this `[['2', '4'], ['4', '7']]` output.But it give me `[['2', '4'], ['5', '2'], ['4', '7']]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you are modifying the list *while* iterating on it! This is almost always a bad idea. Once you delete an element, the other elements get shifted ahead, and this causes your function to "skip" over some elements.

The shortest fix to your algorithm would be iterating on a "copy" of the list, so:

```py
def base_remover(s,l):
    for i in list(l):
        for j in i:
            for k in s:
                if k == j:
                    l.remove(i)
    return l
```

However, a much simpler and single-line solution exists, using list comprehension:

```py
def base_remover(s,l):
    return [el for el in l if not any(es in el for es in s)]
```